# MySQL issue with column name "range"

Tags: mysql, create-table

When I try to run this script I am getting an error at "range" if I remove or change the name I can run the script however the application need this column to store data. Any idea how to insert this into MySQL?

Error Code:
1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"range"              CHAR(5) NOT NULL,     range_max_value         NUMERIC(18,3)' at line 22

```
CREATE TABLE My_table (
  chart_id                INTEGER NOT NULL,
  u_range                 CHAR(5),
  l_range                 CHAR(5),
  "range"               CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  range_max_val         NUMERIC(18,3),
  range_min_val         NUMERIC(18,3),
  PRIMARY KEY (chart_id)
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Range is a reserved keyword that needs to be escaped with backticks.

```
CREATE TABLE My_table (
  chart_id                INTEGER NOT NULL,
  u_range                 CHAR(5),
  l_range                 CHAR(5),
  `range`               CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  range_max_val         NUMERIC(18,3),
  range_min_val         NUMERIC(18,3),
  PRIMARY KEY (chart_id)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) list. *Range* is one of those words. You need to escape it with tick marks:

```
CREATE TABLE My_table (
  chart_id                INTEGER NOT NULL,
  u_range                 CHAR(5),
  l_range                 CHAR(5),
  `range`               CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  range_max_val         NUMERIC(18,3),
  range_min_val         NUMERIC(18,3),
  PRIMARY KEY (chart_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`RANGE` is a reserved word.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html